# Aerospike converting "True/False" boolean to 0/1

Tags: aerospike

When storing the bin "{"india":False}" in aerospike it converts it to  {"india":0} when storing. Is there a way to store booleans in Aerospike- since in strongly typed languages the above gives a type mismatch error.

Answer (score 1):

Boolean type is not yet supported:

1. Aerospike forum (Jan. 1, 2015): ["Boolean is not on our short list (float is), but we are currently adding a few other types as well. We will consider boolean."](https://discuss.aerospike.com/t/boolean-datatype-support/823)
2. As of Mar. 9, 2016, their [changelog](http://www.aerospike.com/download/server/notes.html) hasn't indicated added support for Boolean.

As for the type-mismatch problem, I simply declared TRUE and FALSE constants to handle it, for example:

```
static final long FALSE = 0L;
static final long TRUE = 1L;

// ...

if (result == TRUE) { 
    //Handle true case 
}
```

Comment: Most clients will serialize booleans, store them as bytes, and deserialize them into the boolean type. Do you mind stating which language client you're using?

Comment: I've been using the Java asyncClient's `ExecuteListener`. When I call a UDF that returns false, I get 0 (type Long)